# Why DeepLinks on Android isn't setup correctly on most of the phones

Tags: android-deep-link

I have setup Firebase Auth with email code verification which uses deeplink for authorization verification. Deeplinks works sometimes on my Samsung Note10 but every other phone have to manually setup default links for app.
It is not something you can ask every user to setup links manually for your app to be working correctly.
Here is intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="HOSTNAME"/>
            <data android:path="/"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I am frustrated that this feature just doesn't work. It is more frustrating to find out that after setting up authorization and link sharing system and publishing to market.